# AWS EC2 ENA support for windows 10?

Tags: networking, windows-10, amazon-ec2

Has anybody successfully installed the Elastic Network Adapter on a windows 10 AMI in ec2?

The image doesn't seem run on a t3 instances without ENA installed.